# PHP - SQL Script Creator

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, function

**What I need:**

*An efficent SQL Script builder to replace the one below.*

**The background.**

A really simple program but I need a more efficient way of producing it, the reason I am having this code is I need other developers to be able to create 'modules' on my platform and database tables, but I am blocking them having full access to the core database, they have to use my $api->database->   access layer to access their tables/data. it blocks any request to the core part of my program.

Below is how I expect to use the functions to build the SQL Create Table Script.
SqlField Class/function just returns a flat array of the values passed, nothing special.

```
//The structure of the params are..

//$fields[] = SqlField::create($f_name, $f_type, $null, $auto_inc, $is_pk, $is_unique);
$fields[] = SqlField::create('id', 'int(7)', 0, 1, 1, 1);

$sql = $sqlTable->createTable('MyTableName', $fields );
```

Below is the current function I wrote quickly, but it was getting messy quickly and isnt complete.

```
public function createTable($tableName, $fields = array()) {

    $sql="CREATE TABLE xmod_".$tableName." ( \r\n";
        $isinit = true;

        foreach($fields as $field) {

            $sql .= ($isinit)? "" : ", \r\n" ;

            $isinit = false;

            $sql .= "".$field[0]." ".$field[1]." ";

            if($field[2] == true) {
                $sql .= "NOT NULL ";
            }

            if($field[3] == true) {
                $sql .= "auto_increment ";
            }   



        }

        $isinit = true;

        //Work on the primary keys
        foreach($fields as $field) {



            if($field[4] == 1) {

                $sql .= ($isinit)? "" : ", \r\n" ;
                $isinit = false;

                $sql .= "PRIMARY KEY (".$field[0].")";
            }

        }

        $isinit = true;

        //Work on the unique fields
        foreach($fields as $field) {

            if($field[5] == 1) {

                $sql .= ($isinit)? "" : ", \r\n" ;
                $isinit = false;

                $sql .= "UNIQUE id (".$field[0].")";
            }


        }           

        $sql .= "\r\n )";


        return $sql;



}
```

Comment: SO isn't a place where people will write code for you, it's a place to ask specific programming questions.

Comment: Fair enough, is there a SQL class that is available that does something somilar

Comment: Though I haven't tried it myself CodeIgniter provides something similar. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html

Comment: thanks danneth, this is basicly what im looking for, ill look into it and learn something new!

Comment: @IEnumerable: I made an answer of it that you can accept if you're happy with it as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I haven't tried it myself CodeIgniter provides something similar. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html

(copied from comment)

Comment: sorry it took so long, went out to dinner, CodeIgniter is fantastic, I heard of it but never used it. I will definitely review its code as there is some pretty cool stuff going on there.

Comment: No worries. I'm a big fan of CodeIgniter, it's made my life a lot easier the last couple of years.